# JSP: How to use radiobutton within foreach, with the attribute names/values changing dynamically

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

What I've been trying to do is to display radio buttons with a corresponding value inside a foreach loop. Then, I'd like to retrieve the value of the selected radio button on the next JSP page.

Here is part of my coding.

```
       <form action="EventList_to_seats_servlet" method="POST">     
            //There are irrelevant lines here.
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:forEach var="ID" items="${EventID}">
                //EventID, a list of Integer, comes from the previous servlet, 
                //set in HttpServletRequest
                //i.e. I wrote "request.setAttribute("EventID", EventID);" in the previous step.
                    <li>
                        <%= "Event ID: "%>   ${ID}
                        <input type="radio" name="${EventID}" value="ID" /><br><br>       
                    </li>
                 </c:forEach>
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitOrderID" />
            </c:otherwise>      
        </form>
```

I'd like to retrieve the selected radio button's name and value on the next servlet.

Here is part of the next step (a servlet, called "EventList_to_seats_servlet").

```
BookingInfo bi = new BookingInfo();
//It's a bean dedicated to storing information entered by the client.

bi.setEventID(request.getParameter("ID"));
//It doesn't seem to be the right way to retrieve the selected radio button's name/value
```

I've tested multiple ways to get the value from the JSP to the servlet, but I still can't find out how to do this, particularly because both the radio button's name and value are generated dynamically.

I'd appreciate if you would give any advice.

**P.S.**

I've found a similar posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184959/multiple-radio-button-selection), but I honestly couldn't fully understand it, mainly because I'm not really sure how to use `${ }`. 
`${ }` seems to be used to access values set by HttpServletRequest (i.e. `request.setAttribute("xxx", yyy);`).

However, after I referred to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719632/which-variables-can-be-accessed-with-the-syntax-in-a-struts-tag-in-a-jsp) , I thought `${ }` seemed to be used for getting values from a Bean too.
In the above example, do you think that getting the `yyy` using `${xxx}` is a common to use `${ }` ?

Comment: That looks pretty common to me, you'd need to look into [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for figuring out how that stuff works, or rather, [EL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm) in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm wondering if I could ask a silly question. According to [the second page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm), EL can be used to access "application data stored in JavaBeans components". However, what I'm accessing by my coding above is not a JavaBean, but an attribute which was set by "request.setAttribute("EventID", EventID);" Do you see anything I'm getting wrong?

Comment: No sir, i dont see anything, i belive ${} also looks in your request scope

Comment: I've been reading the links you showed and studying what I didn't know about JSTL & EL... So, if there is only a property's name inside `$(  )`, this `$(  )` is supposed to look at the property of [implicit objects](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=7), but if there is a property attached with its object name , will the `$(  )` search the object's property?

Comment: It seems that I should study them by myself, anyways.

Comment: Yeah, im afraid youve mostly exhausted my trivial knowledge of EL and JSTL :)

Answer (score 0):

Change JSP and Servelet as below:

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="ID" items="${EventID}">

                        <li>
                            <%= "Event ID: "%>   ${ID}
                            <input type="radio" name="selectedValue${id}" value="${ID.id}" /><br><br>       
                        </li>
 </c:forEach>
```

Servlet:

```
 String selected = request.getParameter("selectedProd" + getId());
```

**OR**
Just change JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="ID" items="${EventID}">

                    <li>
                        <%= "Event ID: "%>   ${ID}
                        <input type="radio" name="${EventID}" value="${ID.id}" /><br><br>       
                    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that the "ID" needs to be modified so that it has a property (i.e. ID.id), since the "EventID" is just a List of Integer and it doesn't have such a method. Could you please tell me how you think about it?

Comment: ID.id is loop auto generated id to know the loop index.

Comment: `request.getParameter("selectedProd" + EventID.getId())`   When I tried the first one with my servlet having this line, this produced a compile time error. (There is no symbol for `getId()` at the servlet). At this time, I was prompted to import `com.sun.java.accessibility.util.EventID` at the servlet so there is some kind of progress anyway.

Comment: When I tried your second suggestion, it produced a run time error (It's http 500 error, saying that `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.Integer' does not have the property 'id'.`)